# Rolled marzipan as cake filling?

Tags: cake, almonds, filling

Do people ever use rolled marzipan as a layer between cake layers frosted in buttercream?

Comment: Yes.     But I suspect your actual question is someting along the lines of "What are advantages/disadvantages?" or "What should I keep in mind if doing so?" - perhaps you'd like to expand your question a bit?

Comment: Yes. Even though I'm a huge fan of marzipan, though, I love the taste but would prefer a softer almond paste.

Answer (score 1):

Probably someone has done this. Why not? 
On the other hand, you don't want a thick marzipan layer, because the material is expensive and has a strong taste, so it is more naturally to use the cream as the bulk filling and have a thin cover on top. This makes the cake more stable, too. If the cream serves as the frosting, it has to thicker.

Normally in a cake one often has the harder layer outside and the soft stuff inside.

As an inspiration, here is something that has marzipan on top of a jelly layer
[image: Dominostein]
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominostein